# Git configuration Diff, Merge parameter explanation

Tags: git, merge, diff, external

There are lots of explanations about how to configure git with external diff and merge.

Unfortunately the tutorials did not work for me.

**What I want / need:** Using advance graphical diff like meld, windiff, etc.

**Behavior**

[image]

**System:** 
Windows 7 x64
Non Admin
Having all apps as portable.

To **debug** the issue further I displayed the configuration using

```
$ git config -l
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
pack.packsizelimit=2g
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.required=true
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
credential.helper=manager
user.name=Niehues Thorsten - Munich-MEAG - external
user.email=sniehues@meag.com
merge.tool=kdiff3
mergetool.kdiff3.path=C:/Users/MZ10387/apps/KDiff3-64bit-0.9.98-2/kdiff3.exe
mergetool.kdiff3.trustexitcode=false
diff.guitool=kdiff3
difftool.kdiff3.path=C:/Users/MZ10387/apps/KDiff3-64bit-0.9.98-2/kdiff3.exe
difftool.kdiff3.trustexitcode=false
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
gui.wmstate=normal
gui.geometry=893x435+292+288 175 196
merge.tool=winmerge
```

**This results in the following questions**

- Why is the git gui trying to use Meld? (not in the git-config)
- I do see parameter `merge.tool=kdiff3`, `merge.tool=winmerge` both added via command line from tutorials. Why do they not get overwritten, which one is leading?
- `git diff` returns with no output`

Comment: Could the configuration be local to a repository, or be specified in a different tool outside of .gitconfig? Are you using git from the command line or a graphical tool? Seems graphical judging by your screenshot, could it be that this tool has its own configuration?

Comment: I do use git-bash and git-gui. The error message is from git-gui

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem.So you can try to chang the difftool's path by choosing gitk's "Edit"->"preferences"->"General"->"External diff" setting.Then find the label"External diff tool",click the "choose" botton,choose the right path for your difftool.

Comment: consider adding details about your answer so others can understand it better

Comment: OK,I change my answer.Is it better?

Answer (score 0):

**Work-around**

1. Use SourceTree Portable (download install)
2. Go to Tools → Options → Diff <choose your favourite diff tool>
   This will ask for paths if necessary